# Easiest way to read XML with attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a XML file I would like to read (with xml atrributes). The structure doesn't change, but the content does.

Sample XML: http://www.yr.no/place/Norway/Oslo/Oslo/Oslo/forecast.xml
(The URL must be copied and pasted into address field manually or you'll get a 404 it seems.)

I'm unable to make a XSD from it using this code (and using XSD.EXE):

```
XmlTextReader myXmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader("forecast.xml");
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
myDataSet.ReadXml(myXmlTextReader);
myDataSet.WriteXmlSchema("forecast.xsd");
```

Results in:

```
Column name 'name' is defined for different mapping types.
```

Now, imagine that I'm lazy on top of that and don't feel like spending my whole evening manually mapping XML to my objects. I want managed code objects to be generated for me so I can easily read the data.

What are my options?

...and if anyone knows, what does the XSD convert error message mean?

Comment: I get a 404 following the link -- can you post a small sample of the XML that reproduces the error?

Comment: does "attribute" mean an XML attribute? I suspect not. In which case maybe you should alter your title to something like "Automatic creation of XSD from XML". But until we can see your code we don't know the problem

Comment: @peter It means xml attribute, I'll update content to reflect it - thanks. :)

Comment: it wasn't a 404 it's The connection was reset

      

      
      
      

      
        
        

          

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

        


        
        


    *   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
          moments.

    *   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
          connection.

    *   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
          that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your final point about the Xsd.exe error, it's having problems with the multiple *location* elements.  If you save the xml and rename the first *location* element to something like *baselocation* then it will convert okay.

You may then be able to manually amend the xsd or generated classes to handle this.

Comment: This solved the problem. I would like to award points to @37Stars as well for the LINQ URL, but this answer was the best fit for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going after XML attributes, then why not just load the xml into a XmlDocument. Then you can access the various nodes and attributes.

Comment: Because iterating the document correctly to fill up an object model would require a lot of coding. I want to be able to query the object model using LINQ and I want to be able to DataBind it with MVVM so the object model must be filled completely.

Comment: not necessarily. For a complex object model, you need code to navigate the object model as well, which is not much different from navigating a DOM tree..