# How to access XML String values in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I'm learning to use ReST Web services and I need to find out how to get a specific value from the xml string that is returned.  How can I simply get 1 value from an xml String?  All I want is one value.  Is there some way to convert this string into something with an indexer?

I'm using Yahoo Geocoding service.  Results:

```
<ResultSet version="1.0">
<Error>0</Error>
<ErrorMessage>No error</ErrorMessage>
<Locale>us_US</Locale>
<Quality>87</Quality>
<Found>1</Found>
−
<Result>
<quality>85</quality>
<latitude>86.457310</latitude>
<longitude>-73.262245</longitude>
<offsetlat>46.457311</offsetlat>
<offsetlon>-73.262071</offsetlon>
<radius>500</radius>
<name/>
<line1>1234 N Main St</line1>
<line2>Anytown, New York  12345</line2>
<line3/>
<line4>United States</line4>
<house>1234</house>
<street>N Main St</street>
<xstreet/>
<unittype/>
<unit/>
<postal>12345</postal>
<neighborhood/>
<city>New York</city>
<county>Albany County</county>
<state>New York</state>
<country>United States</country>
<countrycode>US</countrycode>
<statecode>NY</statecode>
<countycode/>
<uzip>12345</uzip>
<hash>E692D20CBDF86A2E</hash>
<woeid>12783988</woeid>
<woetype>11</woetype>
</Result>
</ResultSet>
```

Comment: Maybe simply [`XmlDocument.SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes.aspx)?

Comment: Ok, but how do I get from having a string to an xml document?

Comment: there are many ways to do this, to show you a sample xml would be good

Comment: @BrokenGlass- I understand there are many ways to do it, but I can't seem to find an example for a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XPath to address the node you are interested in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=VS.90).aspx

To transform XML string into an XML document

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(yourString);
```

Here is a good introduction to XPath: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx

Comment: Can I do this using a string in memory instead of an xml file?

Comment: Perfect!  Could you also show an example of how to look at a specific element (node?).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe they didn't include a constructor for strings OR files!  Microsoft....

Answer (score 3):

You could use Linq to XML

```
XDocument xmlfile= XDocument.Load("PATH TO XML DOC");
var test = from xml in xmlfile.Descendants("item_name")
           select new { Title = (string)xml.Element("title").Value };
```

That's one way.

Comment: No file; data comes by way of a string

Comment: Where is the string coming from?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters (a string is a string, isn't it?) but I've added sample xml response to my question.

Answer (score 1):

See my question on [Easiest way to read XML with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797406/easiest-way-to-read-xml-with-attributes). I found that using xsd.exe to generate a xsd which allows you managed access to the XML was the simplest way to access the XML data. LINQ2XML was also pretty easy to use.